# Multiple datasets and fit line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have different datasets:

```
Df1 
X  Y
1  1
2  5
3  14
4  36
5  90

Df2

X  Y
1  1
2  5
3  21
4  38
5  67

Df3

X  Y
1  1
2  5
3  10
4  50
5  78
```

I would like to determine a line which fits this data and plot all data in one chart (like a regression).
On the x axis I have the time; on the y axis I have the frequency of an event that occurs.
Any help on the approach on how to determine the line and plot the results keeping the different legends (would be ok with seaborn or matplotlib) would be helpful.

What I have done so far is plotting the three lines as follows:

```
plot_df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(dataset_list, x_lists, y_lists)),
               columns =['Dataset', 'X', 'Y']).set_index('Dataset', inplace=False)

plot_df= plot_df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index() # this step should transpose the resulting df and explode the values

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))

for name, group in plot_df.groupby('Dataset'):
    group.plot(x = "X", y= "Y", ax=ax, label=name)
```

Please note that the three lists at the beginning contain information on the three different df.

Comment: Have you had a go at any of this problem? if so, please post the code. If not, I would suggest you try plotting the three lines first and then look into fitting lines to data -  there are plenty of questions on here relating to that.

Comment: Thanks @Pepsi-Joe. I already plotted the three lines (I am going to update the question, so you can see the progress), but I do not know how to determine the line that fits data. I just updated the question.

Comment: This is tagged `seaborn`. Have you had a look at the [seaborn resources](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html)? If so, what were the specific problems you encountered?

Comment: I removed the tag. Thanks Mr.T

Comment: Well, seaborn is an excellent tool for plotting regression curves (among many other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `linregress` from `scipy.stats` as this gives very readable code. Just need to add in the logic to your loop:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

for name, group in plot_df.groupby('Dataset'):
    group.plot(x = "X", y= "Y", ax=ax, label=name)
    
    #fit a line to the data
    fit = linregress(group.X, group.Y)
    
    ax.plot(group.X, group.X * fit.slope + fit.intercept, label=f'{name} fit')
```

Comment: Thanks Pepsi-Joe. I fixed this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape', by adding astype(float). I cannot visualize  the equation, though

Comment: Use `label=f'{name} fit y = {fit.slope}x + {fit.intercept}'` to show the equation in the legend.